# Why is the join not rounded when the line doubles back on itself?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have the following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(c, rect);

    CGContextSetLineJoin(c, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextSetLineCap(c, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 50.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 60, 60);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 60, 250);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 60, 249);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 160, 60);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 160, 250);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 160.01, 249);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);
}
```

This generates the following output:

[image: Output of the code]

Is there a good reason that the red shape's bottom edge is not rounded? Or is it a bug in Core Graphics when the line exactly doubles back on itself?

Comment: This no longer seems to happen in the newest iOS version (13) (at least with lines). It still happens when using curves and quad curves though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608766/artefact-drawing-in-swift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely a bug. If you try adding another line to the path, you can see how Core Graphics is unable to handle it.

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 60.0, 60.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 60.0, 250.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 60.0, 249.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 60.0, 250.0);
```

[image]

It's as if the masking that creates the rounded caps and joins gets inverted when it's doubled.

Comment: Of course the *ends* of the line are rounded, that's `CGContextSetLineCap` and is not the question here. The question is why `CGContextSetLineJoin` with `kCGLineJoinRound` does not round the join when the path turns 180° (but does when it turns something like 179.427°).

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the line cap, and overlooked the line join. You've most likely found a bug. The documentation for kCGLineJoinRound clearly states that the joins should be rounded, but they're obviously not.

Answer (score 3):

mortenfast proved this is a bug. But I'll post this answer to offer my workaround.

A workaround is to detect this case and add a very short line segment perpendicular to the existing line, something like this:

```
- (void)addPtToPath:(CGPoint)newPt {
    // CoreGraphics seems to have a bug if a path doubles back on itself.
    // Detect that and apply a workaround.
    CGPoint curPt = CGPathGetCurrentPoint(self.currentPath);
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(newPt, curPt)) {
        CGFloat slope1 = (curPt.y - prevPt.y) / (curPt.x - prevPt.x);
        CGFloat slope2 = (curPt.y - newPt.y) / (curPt.x - newPt.x);
        CGFloat diff;
        BOOL between;
        if (isinf(slope1) && isinf(slope2)) {
            // Special-case vertical lines
            diff = 0;
            between = ((prevPt.y < curPt.y) != (curPt.y < newPt.y));
        } else {
            diff = slope1 - slope2;
            between = ((prevPt.x < curPt.x) != (curPt.x < newPt.x));
        }
        if (between && diff > -0.1 && diff < 0.1) {
            //NSLog(@"Hack alert! (%g,%g) (%g,%g) (%g,%g) => %g %g => %g", prevPt.x, prevPt.y, curPt.x, curPt.y, newPt.x, newPt.y, slope1, slope2, diff);
            if (isinf(slope1)) {
                curPt.x += 0.1;
            } else if (slope1 == 0) {
                curPt.y += 0.1;
            } else if (slope1 < -1 || slope1 > 1) {
                curPt.x += 0.1; curPt.y -= 0.1 / slope1;
            } else {
                curPt.x -= 0.1 * slope1; curPt.y += 0.1;
            }
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(self.currentPath, NULL, curPt.x, curPt.y);
        }
        prevPt = curPt;
    }
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(self.currentPath, NULL, newPt.x, newPt.y);
}
```

This needs one ivar named `prevPt`, and operates on the path in the ivar `currentPath`.